# Python ciscoconfparse - check specific line in a config

Tags: python, ciscoconfparse

I'm trying to get the AAA configuration in my switch to compare the exact configuration, but when i try to gather with the exact same config it doesn't show that as a correct configuration.

Here's the example :

```
def check_config(config):
    parse = CiscoConfParse('test_config.txt', syntax='ios')
    tcs_obj = parse.find_lines(config)
    
    if parse.find_objects(config):
        print(parse.find_objects(config))
    else:
        print(f'Config {config} not found!!!')


check_config('aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local')
```

The result:

`Config aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local not found!!!`

But when i tried to remove the 'local', it showed the line.

```
check_config('aaa authentication login default group tacacs+')
```

`[<IOSCfgLine # 34 'aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local'>]`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because CiscoConfParse objects use regex for their input. So, when you pass `aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local`, the `+` acts as a regex operator.

So, the solution here is to pass a regex string to the function and use the escape character `\` on the regex operator `+`.

Below config works:

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse


def check_config(config):
    parse = CiscoConfParse('test_config.txt', syntax='ios')

    if parse.find_objects(config):
        print(parse.find_objects(config))
    else:
        print(f'Config {config} not found!!!')


check_config(r'aaa authentication login default group tacacs\+ local')
```

All that was updated was the string passed to the function `check_config`. Put an `r` before the quotes and put an escape `\` before the `+` operator.